# How can i load 2 spring context in same JVM?

Tags: spring

I've 2 applications each one uses different spring application context configuration on the same JVM, and every time i tries to run both of them together i found a problem that the last one configuration always overrides the previous one so the spring context loaded with the last one configuration, any advices how to overcome this, by letting every application runs with it's configuration without affected by other spring context.

Comment: Some code and context would go a long way

Comment: applications i runs is a simple java applications that that uses a main() method to instantiate the application context like the below line

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] {"file:///C:/Application1/spring/*.xml" });

in each application i uses the above line but each one refer to a different folder.

Comment: I think you might be getting ClassLoaders and JVMs mixed up. You can create as many Spring contexts as you like, but if you're loading them using classpath-searching, and not using separate ClassLoaders then they will conflict.